# Why is RAS undruggable?

Tags: molecular-genetics, cancer, pharmacology, mutations

1. Why can't mutated RAS get inactivated by GTPase?
2. Why don't we have any inhibitors for RAS-GTP binding?
3. Why is RAS undruggable?
4. How can mutated RAS be inactivated?

I had been researching on the topic and had a lot of doubts in the regard. Please provide me direction, as to where can I find answers to the questions and continue the research "how can mutated RAS be inactivated?"

Comment: This is not one, but four questions and all of them are quite complex - actually these are the key question to treating a lot of cancers. Can you please narrow it down?

Comment: Do you have a reference for question 3? Why do you think RAS is undruggable?

Comment: www.nature.com/nrd/journal/v13/n11/full/nrd4389.html